# How to use print function with Mako templates

Tags: python, templates, cherrypy, mako

heres my problem:

i define a function named "lorem" that should print out some text:

```
    <div id="mainpage">
        <%
        def lorem():
            for i in range(0,50):
                print("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam")
        %>
        ${lorem()}
    </div>
```

But all it does is printing this text on my console, but i want this printed on my site.
I´m using cherrypy and Mako with python 3.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using the [`def` mako tag](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/defs.html#using-defs) it makes life easier.

```
<%def name="lorem()">
% for i in range(0,50):
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
% endfor
</%def>
<div id="mainpage">
    ${lorem()}
</div>
```

Edit: if you want to use a standard python function like you have, you just have to make sure it returns something (print sends output to stdout, not to your mako template).

```
<div id="mainpage">
    <%
    def lorem():
        res = []
        for i in range(0,50):
            res.append("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam")
        return ' '.join(res)
    %>
    ${lorem()}
</div>
```

or use list comprehension

```
return ' '.join([
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam"
    for i in range(0,50)
]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<%
    context.write("Hai")
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just enter the text you want without the print command...

```
<div id="mainpage">
    <%
    def lorem():
        for i in range(0,50):
            return "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam"
    %>
    ${lorem()}
</div>
```

http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/defs.html#using-defs

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i already tried  this but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

You can print to the `context` object:

```
<%
def lorem():
    for i in range(0,50):
        print("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam", file=context)
%>
${lorem()}
```